# How can I in R, group by ID and summarise by mean with na.rm = TRUE

Tags: r, tidyverse

I want to group by ID and summarise, whilst removing NAs.
please see example code below.

```
# Example data
ID <- c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3)
x <- c(2, 3, NA, 2, 3, 1, 1)
ID_x <- tibble(ID, x)

# 1. Works
ID_x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_each(mean)

# 2. Does not work with na.rm=TRUE
ID_x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_each(mean(., na.rm=TRUE))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the lambda (`~`

```
library(dplyr)
ID_x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_each(~ mean(., na.rm=TRUE))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     ID     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   2.5
2     2   2.5
3     3   1
```

---

Also, in recent versions, the `summarise_each` will accompany a warning as these are deprecated in favor of `across`

```
ID_x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A different option would be using `funs`. You can also use this:

```
ID_x %>%
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  summarise_each(funs(mean(., na.rm = TRUE)))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
     ID     x
  <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   2.5
2     2   2.5
3     3   1
```